# How to prevent Ruby OAuth Gem from sending oauth_body_hash in token requests?

Tags: ruby, oauth

I am attempting to authenticate with an OAuth 1.0a provider. However, their implementation of OAuth 1.0a is very strict. From their [documentation](http://www.miicard.com/for/developers/claims-api/using-oauth10a):

> POST parameters prefixed oauth_ that do not form part of the OAuth
>   1.0a protocol will cause the call to fail: do not calculate or supply the oauth_body_hash parameter as it is not part of the OAuth 1.0a
>   protocol
>
> A number of OAuth client libraries fail to implement the OAuth 1.0a
>   specification by supplying oauth_body_hash to token request calls -
>   you must suppress this to succeed in obtaining request and access
>   tokens

How do I stop [oauth](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth/versions/0.4.7) from sending `oauth_body_hash`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request pending to fix this issue:

- [Fix token requests do not include oauth_body_hash **#98**](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/pull/98)

A workaround until #98 is merged is to use the following in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'oauth', github: 'ministrycentered/oauth-ruby'
```